# Show the scrollbar always at top of the page for every next click in android

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am working on android application. In my app I used scrollview. At the top of the page I kept a next button. When clicked on next button the same page will be called. But here I have a problem with scrollview. For the first time when I scrolled the page and clicked on next button it is not going to the top of the page automatically. It is showing from half of the page where I scrolled in the first page. How can I keep the scroll always on the top of the page for every next click action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
ScrollView scvMain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scvMain);
scvMain.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
scvMain.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: hi when i used this it is showing null pointer exception at scvMain.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP); can u tell me why is it so?

Comment: The previous line `ScrollView scvMain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scvMain);`, the findViewById was probably null, could not find the R.id.scvMain in your `R` file which is generated on build. If this gives you problems (anything layout related), `clean and build` should solve your problems

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.?

```
ScrollView myScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView);
myScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

or you can also do like this

```
ScrollView myScrollView = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView));
myScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
    }
});
```